# How to return a managed Boolean from a C++/CLI assembly

Tags: c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI assembly that provides some managed classes that wrap native code. Is it possible to return a *managed* Boolean from methods in the managed classes?

For instance, if I have this method in one such class:

```
bool Func1() { return true; }
```

then, using ILSpy, the return type is marshaled as:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
public bool Func1()
{
    return true;
}
```

I've also tried returning a System::Boolean:

```
System::Boolean Func2() { return true; }
```

but it also marshals using the same unmanaged type:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
public bool Func2()
{
    return true;
}
```

Is it possible to return a managed bool without any marshaling?

Comment: It is in fact a System::Boolean in the assembly metadata as long as you compile with /clr in effect.  ILSpy is not capable of displaying an unmanaged bool, it cannot decompile to native C++ code.  The compiler is just a bit more explicit about the marshaling of the return type than strictly necessary.  That is not unreasonable, *bool* is difficult because the C language did not have it and there are entirely too many typedefs around to add it, few agree about the size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans. I've just checked with ildasm.exe too, and that lists the functions as "Func1 : bool()" and "Func2 : bool()" - which suggests they are managed booleans, although the disassembled IL also says "marshal(unsigned int8)": .method public hidebysig instance bool 
        marshal( bool) 
        Func1a() cil managed

Comment: The ildasm.exe author also decided to decompile System::Boolean to "bool".  A very reasonable choice.  The marshal directive is what got you to see [MarshalAs].  As I said, not strictly necessary but not wrong.  You don't have a problem.

Comment: "You don't have a problem" - Excellent, thanks Hans :)